# How can we predict Geo Tagged Pollution Parameters using a Machine Learning Model with an Android Device?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, predictive-modeling, data-science-model, machine-translation

Newly installed Pollution Control Sensory Platforms are dumping Continous/Discrete Environment Pollution Parametric Data from various locations.

1. Whats the best format structured or Unstructured of data storing efficient from day one and compatible to ML ?
2. What should be the strategy : Supervised or Reinforced or UnSupervised form of ML  ?

End objective is to predict the pollution levels in a specific route and recommend/alert the time for Bicycling , Walking and Running for sports enthusiasts .